# C++ - Static_assert and ability of constexpr functions to evaluate at runtime

Tags: c++, constexpr, static-assert

I'm reading about `constexpr` and `static_assert` features in C++ and one thing seems confusing to me - I've read that `constexpr` functions are not necessarily always evaluated during compilation and they can sometimes evaluate at runtime. One thing that bothers me is that `static_assert` is always checked during compilation. So what happens, if we pass `constexpr` to `static_assert`, but compiler chooses to evaluate that `constexpr` during runtime? Is that even an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> constexpr functions are not necessarily always evaluated during compilation

It is always evaluated at compile time when it should be, so when its return value is used as const expression.

`static_assert` is one of this case.
`constexpr int value = f();` or `C<f()> c;`(template argument) are other cases.

but in `std::cout << f()`, it is not required to be computed at compile time.

And in `void bar(int p) { const int v = f(p);}`, `f` cannot be evaluated as `constexpr` (depend of parameter of function which are not (cannot be)  `constexpr`).

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not an issue. The standard says that if it evaluates to true the statement has no effect (and if it evaluates to false the program is ill-formed). A consequence of this is that if evaluated at runtime the expression may not have any (observable) side effects (directly or indirectly).

That the compiler is allowed to evaluate constant expressions during runtime doesn't relieve the compiler from the burden of evaluating this expression at compile time anyway. This is because the compiler has to provide diagnostic message if it's not `true`.